# Dynamically change About dialog text in RCP based application

Tags: rcp

Are is possible to dynamically change About dialog text in RCP based application? I want to replace aboutText value when About dialog opens by dynamically changing some part of it's text. Problem is that I has a client/server application, where information about client can be static, but server information (at least version string) may change independently and I don't know when it will happen. aboutText itself is static text. about.mapping approach also not work, because this file is packed into application JAR and because of this is read-only too. Are there is a possibility to subclass aboutText or update it in another way before About dialog show it? I not want to rewrite the all Eclipse About dialog class from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use system properties in about.mappings to achieve this:

Create an about.mappings file at the root of your app plugin

Add lines such as 0=$net.dnorth.about.text$

Reference {0} in the aboutText set in plugin.properties

Now call System.setProperty("net.dnorth.about.text", "your dynamic text here") in some code at start-up.

Reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=172692

Answer (score 0):

The about text of the IDE is instance specific i.e if you are running a RCP application then at that time you cant change the About text.It is only possible if you update your RCP with via Check for updates link or if you install another IDE over the present one.

I these two cases only you can change your about text.